# Assigning existing or empty object

Tags: javascript

This might be a duplicate but I did not know how to search for it.

Why does

```
var test = test || {};
```

work, but

```
var test = testing || {};
```

throws an error? At the point of definition both `test` and `testing` are undefined.

**Edit**

The error thrown is "Reference Error: testing is not defined"

Comment: @MattLin: But I did not define `test` either, or did I?

Comment: @nozzleman: What? Just copy and paste `var test = testing || {};` to your console.

Comment: @Amberlamps yeah, nevermind, i got your question wrong, thought you did declare `var testing` before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between a variable being undefined in the sense of not existing and a variable holding the value `undefined`.

In your first example you declare `test` with `var` such that when the expression on the right of the `=` is evaluated the variable `test` exists but has the value `undefined`.

In your second example you haven't defined `testing` at all, hence the error.

EDIT: It occurs to me that perhaps further explanation wouldn't hurt.

To simplify, the JavaScript engine takes two passes through the code. The first pass is the parse/compile phase, and it is then that variable declarations *but not assignments* happen. The second pass is the actual execution, and it is then that assignments occur. This results in an effect often called "variable hoisting" - it is as if the JS engine "hoists" the declarations to the top of their scope but still does the assignments in place.

So as to the point of code like this:

```
var test = test || {};
```

...it is basically saying "Does `test` already exist with a truthy value? If so use it, otherwise set it to a new empty object."

The JS engine doesn't mind if the same variable is declared more than once in the same scope - it basically ignores the second *declaration,* but doesn't ignore any *assignment* included with the second declaration. So if `test` is declared in some other script block, perhaps in a separate JS include file, then the line in question just assigns `test` to itself (assuming it has a truthy value, where all objects are truthy). But if it hasn't been declared elsewhere it will still exist as a result of the current `var` statement but it will be `undefined` before the current assignment so then the `||` operator returns the right-hand operand, the `{}`.

Comment: `There's a difference between a variable being undefined in the sense of not existing and a variable holding the value undefined.`. This is the line. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the `var` keyword.
Because the variable is declared it also exists albeit with the value undefined. What the `||` then does is to check for truthiness and when it finds that the object is undefined it gives you a new object to work with.

The latter does the exact same but since you're doing it on "one line" the `testing` object isn't defined when evaluated and thusly throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = test || {};
```

Here, `test` has been `declared` but not `defined`

but in,

```
var test = testing || {};
```

There's no reference of `testing` whatsoever and you are still trying to assign its value.

A corresponding code for the first case would be,

```
var testing;  // See testing is still undefined
var test = testing || {};
```